# Scrape span content as a list in Google Plus page with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, text-extraction

I just discovered CasperJS and I'd like to use it to scrape data on a web page. It's for a list of items and I just need to get their label. Here is the html structure of the page:

```
<div class="xT X8c" data-id="1">
  <a class="d-s ob" tabindex="0" target="_top" href="114095242435722376870">
     <div class="l0d">
        <div class="n0d">
          <a class="d-s ob yTc q0d" oid="114095242435722376870" tabindex="0" target="_top" href="114095242435722376870">
              <span class="VCc">Text to retrieve</span>
          </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Z8c"></div>
    <div class="XEd" data-tooltip-align="b,c"></div>
</div>
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="2">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="3">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="4">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="5">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="6">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="7">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="8">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="9">
<div class="xTc X8c" data-id="10">'
```

I need to retrive the "Text to retrieve" in each instance of the "xTc X8c" class. The ids are not that simple (I put fake for the example) and I don't know the number of instance there can be in the page.

I tried to reach directly all the "span.VCc" class with this code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var name = [];

function getSpanTexts() {
    var texts = document.querySelectorAll('span.VCc');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(texts, function(e) {
        return e.textContent;
    });
}


casper.start('https://plus.google.com/communities/106508855808848733254/members');

casper.then(function() {
  name = this.evaluate(getSpanTexts);
  this.echo('fonction en cours');
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(name.length + ' names found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + name.join('\n - ')).exit();
});.
```

But it doesn't work: 
- It says name tab has 129 lines (should retrieve 10 results)
- And it doesn't display anything :/

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Google shows different markup of their pages depending on user agent string and viewport size. Dump the source and see whether your elements are there. Maybe those elements are even in an iframe.

Comment: So you mean that the CSS changes depending on the user who is going on the page ? 
I'd like to scrap the names of the member of a community.  

I'm not sure to get your point ? :/ (I'm new to casperjs, started to look at it yesterday)

Comment: No, it changes according to the browser (PhantomJS vs. Chrome) that you use. See how the page looks by dumping the content: `casper.debugHTML()`